# Unable to install IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation 7.1 using cocoapods

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

We are trying to configure our native iOS app to MFP 7.1 using cocoapods. However, when we define the **IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation** in our podfile and try `pod install`, we are getting the below error:

```
[!] Error installing IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://hub.jazz.net/git/imflocalsdk/imf-client-sdks /var/folders/94/h6b7y6wx5k1dc_4q2xj5_8hw0000gn/T/d20170911-59452-jm2y5r --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation_7.1.11

Cloning into '/var/folders/94/h6b7y6wx5k1dc_4q2xj5_8hw0000gn/T/d20170911-59452-jm2y5r'...
fatal: Remote branch IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation_7.1.11 not found in upstream origin
```

We have followed the below Doc but we couldn't get it to work.

[Adding the IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation iOS SDK to a new application with CocoaPods](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/t_dev_new_w_cocoapods.html)

PodFile:

```
# platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'test' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Alamofire', '4.5.0'
  pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '4.1.0'
  pod 'DatePickerCell', '1.0.5'
  pod 'ObjectMapper', '2.2.8'
  pod 'OHHTTPStubs/Swift'
  pod 'SkyFloatingLabelTextField', '3.1.0'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '3.1.4'
  pod 'Toast-Swift', '2.0.0'
  pod 'Pulley', '1.3.1'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation', '~> 7.1'

  target 'test' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

  target 'test' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

end

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!
#target :name-of-the-target-in-xcode-project do
platform :ios, 10.0
pod 'IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation', '~> 7.1'
```

Comment: Did you find the solution yet?

Comment: We had to do it manually using (https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/hello-world/configuring-a-native-ios-application-with-the-mfp-sdk/#localMethod)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is caused due to recent git migration from hub.jazz.net to git.ng.bluemix.net where all of the Mobilefirst SDKs source were hosted on hub.jazz.net repo and now it is unavailable. This in-turn caused `pod install` failure.

**Note:** You can also get MFP 7.1 iOS SDKs using MFP 7.1 Studio Plugin as mentioned in [this](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/hello-world/configuring-a-native-ios-application-with-the-mfp-sdk/#localMethod) blog post.